# mvc || can not be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to do a search by either FirstName or Lastname. And I want the list shows every single record if search is null. I bump into an error '| can not be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string' '.

Here's my index controller

```
 [Authorize(Users="aaron")]
public class personController : Controller
{
    private dumb_so_dumbEntities db = new dumb_so_dumbEntities();

    // GET: /person/
    public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {

        if (searchBy == "FirstName")
        {
            return View(db.Persons.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.Persons.Where(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList());
        }

    }
```

Also, I have an additional question. If I want to add additional search function but it's an int(name as P_Id). How can I put all three(one int and two strings) together in one action?
I did try do a

```
else if (searchBy == "P_Id")
```

It kicks back as something like can not convert int to string.

Comment: You should add a tag to your question to say what language this is in (C#?). It'll help the right people find it.

Comment: Are you certain of the code you submitted ? This works on my side. Can't the error come from somewhere else?

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://ideone.com/Nde7dj). I interverted the test for null to avoid another error, but otherwise, works.

Comment: @X.L.Ant This is the code...

Answer (score 0):

Try `Contains` instead like this:

```
[Authorize(Users="aaron")]
public class personController : Controller 
{
    private dumb_so_dumbEntities db = new dumb_so_dumbEntities();

// GET: /person/
    public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {

        if (searchBy == "FirstName")
        {
            return View(db.Persons.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(search) || search == null).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.Persons.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(search) || search == null).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
For your second question you can convert your `ints` to `strings` like this:

```
string convertedInteger = intToConvert.ToString();
```

and then do your `ìf` comparison

Comment: `Where` takes a function as parameter, not a boolean. This wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Celt Thanks Celt. still error but as 'operator || can not be applied to operands of type 'system.linq.IQueryable <WebApplication2.Models.Person>' and 'bool'  '

Comment: Try `contains` instead of `StartsWith`

Comment: @Celt  It works now(without additional brackets)!! What's wrong with StartsWith...

Comment: Nice one! I think it's because `Contains` works on a string basis but `StartsWith` doesn't - just a guess though

Comment: @Celt Thanks a lot Celt. I have an additional question. I just edited the main question body. Appreciate that!

Comment: Sorry I think you'll need to be a bit clearer on what you're asking and add more code..

Comment: I updated the answer with the info I think you need, could you mark it as correct if it is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {
        if (searchBy == "FirstName")
        {
            return View((from o in db.Persons Where o.LastName.StartsWith(search) select o).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
         //if searchBy not "FirstName" including null then select all data..
          return View((from o in db.Persons select o).ToList());
        }

    }
```

and:

```
string myValue="your_value";

return View((from o in db.Persons Where (o.LastName.StartsWith(search)) || (o.Name==myValue) select o).ToList());
```